# Parquet raw file content seems incomplete vs content displayed in databricks

Tags: parquet, azure-databricks

I'm doing a string search for certain values that I would expect to be in a parquet file. Some are found, others are not found.

Yet when I view the parquet file content from a databricks notebook, I can find a missing value within the data shown.

Approx 70% of the data I search for with the raw parquet file (on windows) is found. But spot checks for some of the remaining data is found via the notebook.

Why is some data present when viewing the raw parquet content and other data isn't? It's also the same data each time which is or isn't found.

Here's a screenshot example. It shows a case where a value from input json IS found in the raw parquet, and a case where a value from input json is not found in raw parquet (but IS found in a csv export of same data from databricks)

[image: example]

Comment: Could you give us some examples and/or screenshots of the situation ?

Comment: Thanks - added screenshot

Comment: How do you load the parquet file ? Any chance that it is a delta file instead ?

Comment: @axle I just download the resulting .parquet file from storage, and use powershell to do a string search through it for the same values as I extract from the input json file. But the same result applies if I use a tool like notepad++ to search the parquet file. It's definitely not the file from the delta_log folder (which is a .crc and .json file)

Comment: If it is a delta file, when you load it, only the latest data is loaded. You might find the data you are looking for with the delta format feature Time Travel : https://databricks.com/blog/2019/02/04/introducing-delta-time-travel-for-large-scale-data-lakes.html